# Error al crear trigger como SYS en Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

Pues ese es el problema , voy a crear triggers en Sql devleoper como SYS , y cuando ejecuto el script , no me deja , algún consejo de como arreglarlo?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en que no deberías estar usando el usuario `SYS` para tu desarollo. Ese usuario es muy especial, y solo deberías usarlo para hacerle un startup/shutdown o un upgrade a tu base de datos. Usar `SYS` para tu desarollo es muy peligroso y puedes causar daño irreparable a tu base de datos.

El error que obtienes es una de las maneras en que la base de datos está tratando de protegerse de cambios peligrosos.

Para evitar el error, usa un usuario diferente, como `SYSTEM` si quieres. O mejor aún, crea un usuario separado, y haz tu trabajo usando ese usuario diferente. No recibirás el error si usas un usuario diferente.

Comment: Cómo podría crear un usuario separado?

Comment: En caso de meter con SYSTEM , también tendría que crearlo con el rol SYSDBA?

Comment: No, no uses SYSDBA. Eso es demasiado poderoso y peligroso.  El usuario `SYSTEM` ya es `DBA`, lo que es mas que suficiente, probablemente demasiado, pero bueno... Si deseas crear otro usuario, en SQL Developer, busca la seccion "Other Users" en la mano izquierda, y haz un clic de la derecha, y puedes hacer "Create User..."